# UIImageView get the position of the showing Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView which shows an UIImage.

The UIImage may change to other UIImage in different size, and the position and the size of the UIImage inside will change according according to it.

My Problem is that i'm trying add a view that will be at the end of the UIImage (which change all the time) and all I can get is the frame of the UIImageView (which stay full screen all the time).

How can i get the "frame" of current showing UIImage ?

Comment: There is no direct API to get that info. You will need to calculate it yourself based on the image view's frame, the image size, and the `contentMode` of the image view.

Comment: @rmaddy that's sounds like a very hard thing to tell. isn't there a way to hack it in a simpler way ?

Comment: You can use the Imageview.image.size.width/height to get the witdth and height. Though i do not know  about the origin.x and y properties

Comment: lets start this way, please post your code showing how you load the image to the imageview

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following will answer your question, assuming your UIImageView used UIViewContentModeAspectFit:

You have to regard the image sizing of the image inside UIImageView. This depends on how you set the contentMode. According your description, I assume you are using UIViewContentModeAspectFit. The resulting image will also be centered in the UIImageView so you also have to consider this for the calculation.

```
-(CGRect )calculateClientRectOfImageInUIImageView:(UIImageView *)imgView
{
    CGSize imgViewSize=imgView.frame.size;                  // Size of UIImageView
    CGSize imgSize=imgView.image.size;                      // Size of the image, currently displayed

    // Calculate the aspect, assuming imgView.contentMode==UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

    CGFloat scaleW = imgViewSize.width / imgSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleH = imgViewSize.height / imgSize.height;
    CGFloat aspect=fmin(scaleW, scaleH);

    CGRect imageRect={ {0,0} , { imgSize.width*=aspect, imgSize.height*=aspect } };

    // Note: the above is the same as :
    // CGRect imageRect=CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width*=aspect,imgSize.height*=aspect) I just like this notation better

    // Center image

    imageRect.origin.x=(imgViewSize.width-imageRect.size.width)/2;
    imageRect.origin.y=(imgViewSize.height-imageRect.size.height)/2;

    // Add imageView offset

    imageRect.origin.x+=imgView.frame.origin.x;
    imageRect.origin.y+=imgView.frame.origin.y;

    return(imageRect);
}
```

For a better illustration of the differences between the three content modes, see below:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this solution assume `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and not `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`? If you used `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` then there is no calculation needed.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's ..AspectFit of course. However, if ...AslectFill is needed you will also need to do some calculations as the image could be cropped at the top or left in case it doesn't fit into the UIImageView without changing the with/height ratio. This is the difference between ...AspectFill and ...ScaleToFill.

Comment: @Marcus I'm not sure I understood your comment. If you used `AspectFill` or `ScaleToFill` then no calculations are needed in those cases because they both will fill the image view. The difference between the two is only the way it scales. The former scales the image until the entire image view is filled while maintaining the aspect ratio which means the image can be out of the frame, while the latter will stretch the image to fill the image view without maintaining aspect ratio and therefore the entire image will be visible.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about returning the rect of the visible portion of the image in the imageview.

Answer (score 27):

## Swift 4.2 & 5.0

```
func calculateRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: UIImageView) -> CGRect {
        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
        let imgSize = imageView.image?.size

        guard let imageSize = imgSize else {
            return CGRect.zero
        }

        let scaleWidth = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width
        let scaleHeight = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height
        let aspect = fmin(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

        var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width * aspect, height: imageSize.height * aspect)
        // Center image
        imageRect.origin.x = (imageViewSize.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2
        imageRect.origin.y = (imageViewSize.height - imageRect.size.height) / 2

        // Add imageView offset
        imageRect.origin.x += imageView.frame.origin.x
        imageRect.origin.y += imageView.frame.origin.y

        return imageRect
    }
```

## Swift 3.0

```
// MARK: - Create Rect
func calculateRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: UIImageView) -> CGRect {
    let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
    let imgSize = imageView.image?.size

    guard let imageSize = imgSize, imgSize != nil else {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    let scaleWidth = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width
    let scaleHeight = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height
    let aspect = fmin(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

    var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width * aspect, height: imageSize.height * aspect)
    // Center image
    imageRect.origin.x = (imageViewSize.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2
    imageRect.origin.y = (imageViewSize.height - imageRect.size.height) / 2

    // Add imageView offset
    imageRect.origin.x += imageView.frame.origin.x
    imageRect.origin.y += imageView.frame.origin.y

    return imageRect
}
```

## For Swift < 3.0

Here is the above method in Swift. Again, assuming that `contentMode` is set to `.ScaleAspectFit` If there is no image on the given `imageView` `CGRectZero` will be returned.

```
func calculateRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: UIImageView) -> CGRect {
    let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
    let imgSize = imageView.image?.size

    guard let imageSize = imgSize where imgSize != nil else {
        return CGRectZero
    }

    let scaleWidth = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width
    let scaleHeight = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height
    let aspect = fmin(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

    var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width * aspect, height: imageSize.height * aspect)
    // Center image 
    imageRect.origin.x = (imageViewSize.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2
    imageRect.origin.y = (imageViewSize.height - imageRect.size.height) / 2

    // Add imageView offset
    imageRect.origin.x += imageView.frame.origin.x
    imageRect.origin.y += imageView.frame.origin.y

    return imageRect
}
```

Comment: How do I use this to take a screenshot of only the image on a screen?

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using built in function AVMakeRectWithAspectRatio.

```
func AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(_ aspectRatio: CGSize, _ boundingRect: CGRect) -> CGRect
```

**Parameters:**

**aspectRatio:**
The width and height ratio (aspect ratio) you want to maintain.

**boundingRect:**
    The bounding rectangle you want to fit into.

**Return Value**
Returns a scaled CGRect that maintains the aspect ratio specified by aspectRatio that fits within bounding Rect.

let boundingBox = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(backgroundImage.size, frame)

Answer (score 6):

Based on the wonderfully simple solution from Janusz, here's what I did:

```
let visibleRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height), insideRect: self.frame)
if visibleRect.contains(point) {
    // Do something great here...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

I know its quite late but might help someone in future. Its very simple and inbuilt solution provided by iOS. Just need to:

`import AVFoundation

let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: self.imageView.bounds)`